# md-datepicker calender not displaying

Tags: datepicker, angular-material

Here's the exact problem I am facing :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdwOLr?editors=1010
Below is the html file :

```
<body layout="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-cloak>
 <md-datepicker 
   ng-model="myDate"
   md-max-date="todaysDate" 
   md-placeholder="Enter date">
 </md-datepicker>
</body>
```

And this is the js file:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial']).config(['$mdDateLocaleProvider',
 function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
     return moment(date).format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
   };
 }
]).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todaysDate = new Date();
}]);
```

The problem : on clicking the datepicker, the dates are not shown. However, after scrolling the dates are displayed, but goes to a far date value.

Additional Information :
Versions -

1. angular = 1.6.0
2. angular-material = 1.1.1
3. moment = 2.17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with your codepen and if you use Angular version 1.5 (and aria / animate to 1.5.1) then the `<md-datepicker>` shows the dates.

If you look at https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10111 then you will see that angular material 1.1.1 is not compatibel to Angular 1.6.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the quick reply. Looking on the link provided by you, the workaround is to set `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);` . I tried this and it **worked**. I didn't know what _preAssignBindingsEnabled()_ does on reading its description on (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) I am not that clear with its concept. Thus, hoping it won't affect anything else, and it is safe to set `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);`

Comment: @SHRUTHIBHARADWAJ Could you please provide code for your changes? I am stuck with same problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @akash, sorry for the late reply. In my app.config() method, I set `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true); `

Comment: Thanks for reply @SHRUTHIBHARADWAJ. I have fixed it by implementing `parseDate` and `formatDate` methods of `mdDateLocaleProvider`.